# How do I set the height of a css element based on the randomly generated height of another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to create a consistent gap of 100px between two 'walls', one on the top of the screen 'wallTop' and one on the bottom 'wallBot', like in Flappy Bird. I've used Math.random on 'wallTop' to randomise the height of it in order to randomise the position of the gap, but how do I set the height of 'wallBot' to be based off of 'wallTop's randomised height?

Here's what I've tried

```
var wallGap = 100;
var wallTop = document.getElementById("wallTop");
var constant= (wallTop.height+wallGap);

$("#wallTop").css("height",Math.round(Math.random()*150+70)+"px");
$("#wallBot").css("height",450-constant+"px");
```

"450" is the height of the whole container, so I'm trying to find the remainder after subtracting 'wallTop' and 'wallGap', which will be the height of 'wallBot'.

Comment: use calc() function: calc(100% - varHeight)
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your `constant` won't change magically after having set a new height for `wallTop` (also note that `wallTop.height` will be `undefined`, since the element doesn't have the property `height`).

```
    var wallGap = 100;
    var wallSpace = 450 - wallGap;
    var wallTop = $("#wallTop");
    var wallBot = $("#wallBot");

    wallTop.height(Math.round(Math.random()*150+70));
    wallBot.height(wallSpace - wallTop.height());
```